# Issue with vertex size

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a graph of which I am unable to reduce the size of the vertex (node). Is there any command for adjusting the size of the vertex. My tex file is

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage[upright]{fourier}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{sagetex}


\begin{document}

%\begin{center} %% commented out by Andrew


\begin{tikzpicture}
\GraphInit[vstyle=Welsh]
%\tikzset{VertexStyle/.style = {shape=triangle}}
\Vertices[unit=3]{circle}{$0$,$a$,$2a$,$b$,$2b$,$a+b$,$2a+2b$,$a+2b$,$2a+b$}
%\SetVertexNoLabel
\AddVertexColor{black}{$0$,$a$,$2a$,$b$,$2b$,$a+b$,$2a+2b$,$a+2b$,$2a+b$}

%\Edges(G,E,F,G,B,D,E,C,D,A,C,B,A)\Edges(B,E)
\Edges($a$,$b$)
\Edges($a$,$2b$)
\Edges($a$,$a+b$)
\Edges($a$,$2a+2b$)
\Edges($a$,$a+2b$)
\Edges($a$,$2a+b$)
\Edges($2a$,$b$)
\Edges($2a$,$2b$)
\Edges($2a$,$a+b$)
\Edges($2a$,$2a+2b$)
\Edges($2a$,$a+2b$)
\Edges($2a$,$2a+b$)
\Edges($b$,$a+b$)
\Edges($b$,$2a+2b$)
\Edges($b$,$a+2b$)
\Edges($b$,$2a+b$)
\Edges($2b$,$a+b$)
\Edges($2b$,$2a+2b$)
\Edges($2b$,$a+2b$)
\Edges($2b$,$2a+b$)
\Edges($a+b$,$a+2b$)
\Edges($a+b$,$2a+b$)
\Edges($2a+2b$,$a+2b$)
\Edges($2a+2b$,$2a+b$)
%\Edges($a+b$,$$)
%\Edges($a+b$,$$)
%\Edges($a+b$,$$)
%\Edges($a+b$,$$)
%\Edges($a+b$,$$)
%\Edges($a+b$,$$)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Your file does not compile...you need to delete the `\begin{center}`, which I guess I can do for you. Which vertex do you want to reduce? Do you just want to remove the vertex labelled `0`?

Comment: Actually, I want to reduce the black dot size of all the vertices. Thank you for your participation Andrew.

Answer (score 3):

To change/set the size of the vertices it is enough to redefine `VertexSmallMinSize`. For example, with

```
\renewcommand*{\VertexSmallMinSize}{2pt}
```

(the default is `12pt`), your graph becomes

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage[upright]{fourier}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{sagetex}


\begin{document}

\renewcommand*{\VertexSmallMinSize}{2pt}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\GraphInit[vstyle=Welsh]
%\tikzset{VertexStyle/.style = {shape=triangle}}
\Vertices[unit=3]{circle}{$0$,$a$,$2a$,$b$,$2b$,$a+b$,$2a+2b$,$a+2b$,$2a+b$}
%\SetVertexNoLabel
\AddVertexColor{black}{$0$,$a$,$2a$,$b$,$2b$,$a+b$,$2a+2b$,$a+2b$,$2a+b$}

%\Edges(G,E,F,G,B,D,E,C,D,A,C,B,A)\Edges(B,E)
\Edges($a$,$b$)
\Edges($a$,$2b$)
\Edges($a$,$a+b$)
\Edges($a$,$2a+2b$)
\Edges($a$,$a+2b$)
\Edges($a$,$2a+b$)
\Edges($2a$,$b$)
\Edges($2a$,$2b$)
\Edges($2a$,$a+b$)
\Edges($2a$,$2a+2b$)
\Edges($2a$,$a+2b$)
\Edges($2a$,$2a+b$)
\Edges($b$,$a+b$)
\Edges($b$,$2a+2b$)
\Edges($b$,$a+2b$)
\Edges($b$,$2a+b$)
\Edges($2b$,$a+b$)
\Edges($2b$,$2a+2b$)
\Edges($2b$,$a+2b$)
\Edges($2b$,$2a+b$)
\Edges($a+b$,$a+2b$)
\Edges($a+b$,$2a+b$)
\Edges($2a+2b$,$a+2b$)
\Edges($2a+2b$,$2a+b$)
%\Edges($a+b$,$$)
%\Edges($a+b$,$$)
%\Edges($a+b$,$$)
%\Edges($a+b$,$$)
%\Edges($a+b$,$$)
%\Edges($a+b$,$$)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit**

As requested in the comments, if you want to rescale the entire picture, say to 50%, then you can do this using

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

With the graph above this results in the  smaller diagram:

[image]

Note that the `scale=0.5` only rescales the "graphics elements" of the `tikzpcture` environment and that it will not affect things like the node text or the size of the nodes. For completeness, here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage[upright]{fourier}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{sagetex}


\begin{document}

\tikzset{VertexStyle/.append style={minimum size=1pt}}

\renewcommand*{\VertexSmallMinSize}{1pt}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\GraphInit[vstyle=Welsh]
\Vertices[unit=3]{circle}{$0$,$a$,$2a$,$b$,$2b$,$a+b$,$2a+2b$,$a+2b$,$2a+b$}
%\SetVertexNoLabel
\AddVertexColor{black}{$0$,$a$,$2a$,$b$,$2b$,$a+b$,$2a+2b$,$a+2b$,$2a+b$}

%\Edges(G,E,F,G,B,D,E,C,D,A,C,B,A)\Edges(B,E)
\Edges($a$,$b$)
\Edges($a$,$2b$)
\Edges($a$,$a+b$)
\Edges($a$,$2a+2b$)
\Edges($a$,$a+2b$)
\Edges($a$,$2a+b$)
\Edges($2a$,$b$)
\Edges($2a$,$2b$)
\Edges($2a$,$a+b$)
\Edges($2a$,$2a+2b$)
\Edges($2a$,$a+2b$)
\Edges($2a$,$2a+b$)
\Edges($b$,$a+b$)
\Edges($b$,$2a+2b$)
\Edges($b$,$a+2b$)
\Edges($b$,$2a+b$)
\Edges($2b$,$a+b$)
\Edges($2b$,$2a+2b$)
\Edges($2b$,$a+2b$)
\Edges($2b$,$2a+b$)
\Edges($a+b$,$a+2b$)
\Edges($a+b$,$2a+b$)
\Edges($2a+2b$,$a+2b$)
\Edges($2a+2b$,$2a+b$)
%\Edges($a+b$,$$)
%\Edges($a+b$,$$)
%\Edges($a+b$,$$)
%\Edges($a+b$,$$)
%\Edges($a+b$,$$)
%\Edges($a+b$,$$)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Andrew. And if I have to reduce the size of the whole graph then what command I should use?

Comment: You can add `[scale=0,5]`, for example, after `\begin{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: No its not working.

Comment: @Parama Perhaps we are talking about different things: see my edit.

Comment: It's working now Andrew. Thank you very much for your help.